# create temporary user accounts oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, user-accounts

I would like to hear your opinion or how you deal with such cases in practice.

It is about an external person being selected by a user who is already registered in the system.
The information is stored in a staging table for the time being. The internal user expects an answer from the external person, who is unknown to the system.
The external person has two options

- Accept
- Reject

  - First case: If the external person accepts, he/she must first make some entries, these should also be stored in the staging table for the time being. However, in order to make these entries, the person must logically register in the system?
  - Second case: If the external person rejects, it would be superfluous for this person to register in the system.But how can I save and retrieve this answer in order to show it to the internal person?
- Does the external person have to register first in order to be able to give an answer (of any kind) so that this answer can be saved and retrieved?
- If the person registers in the system, where should personal data be stored, also in a staging table?

I know this answer is very superficial, I am new to development and wonder how temporary user accounts in the system are generally handled in practice.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, you'd create a **public** page (i.e. the one that doesn't require any authentication) and let those "external" people visit it and either accept or reject what's being offered.

Their answer can be stored into a database; I'd suggest you not to create a region which has actual table behind it, but call a **stored procedure** which will accept certain parameters (external person's answer and possibly some other data) and perform an `INSERT` operation to the database table.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I have a supplementary question and that is when the internal person enters data such as email of the external person in the form, is this also stored in the staging table along with the form ID so that you know which form the external person is assigned to.

When the person gives an answer or enters their data, I want to update the tables to the one with the form ID. 
How can I retrieve this ID on the public page and also the entered data of the internal person?

Comment: External person should be able to fetch the ID, somehow - a Select List item might be one option. Then, select any other data you want (based on selected form ID).

Comment: Thank you little foot, I decided to let the external person to insert his/her email based on this I can fetch the ID. For this I created a function.